# Need help to extract function information from c header

Tags: ctags

How I can extract the function prototype information form C header? I want my data to in following format.

function_name:return_type:signature

My preference is ctags.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Universal-ctags(https://ctags.io), following command line is for printing the information in the format:

```
$ u-ctags --language-force=C -x --_xformat="%N:%{typeref}:%{signature}"  --kinds-C=p foo.h
```

Here is an example:

```
 $ ./ctags --language-force=C -x --_xformat="%N:%{typeref}:%{signature}"  --kinds-C=p /usr/include/stdio.h | head
__asprintf:int:(char ** __restrict __ptr,const char * __restrict __fmt,...)
__getdelim:_IO_ssize_t:(char ** __restrict __lineptr,size_t * __restrict __n,int __delimiter,FILE * __restrict __stream)
__isoc99_fscanf:int:(FILE * __restrict __stream,const char * __restrict __format,...)
__isoc99_scanf:int:(const char * __restrict __format,...)
__isoc99_sscanf:int:(const char * __restrict __s,const char * __restrict __format,...)
__isoc99_vfscanf:int:(FILE * __restrict __s,const char * __restrict __format,_G_va_list __arg)
__isoc99_vscanf:int:(const char * __restrict __format,_G_va_list __arg)
__isoc99_vsscanf:int:(const char * __restrict __s,const char * __restrict __format,_G_va_list __arg)
asprintf:int:(char ** __restrict __ptr,const char * __restrict __fmt,...)
clearerr:void:(FILE * __stream)
```

Comment: There is one case where it doesn't work as I want:
For example, if my header is like:

#include <stdio.h>
int first (int a, int b);
struct mystructure second (int a);
long long third (long a);

Output using mentioned command:

first:int:(int a,int b)
second:mystructure:(int a)
third:long long:(long a)

Here ctags does not consider the struct keyword for the second function.

I am using Universal Ctags 0.0.0(44a0e97)
Exuberant Ctags 5.8

Is there any way to keep struct keyword.

Comment: I see. It looks a bug. Could you open an issue at https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/issues ?

Comment: Ok sure I will do that.